# CSS animation does not work in Mozilla but works in Chrome. the solution?

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, cross-browser, mozilla

**Please look at my code**

Html :

```
`<div id="animated-example" class="animated swing"><div class="navbar"></div></div>`
```

Css :

```
.animated {

    color: #9f9f9f;

    min-height: 300px;

    width: 100%;   

    padding-bottom: 24px;

    background: #000000 url(../images/icons.svg) repeat center; 

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;

    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -webkit-animation-duration:15s;

    -moz-animation-duration:15s;

    -o-animation-duration:15s;

    animation-duration:15s;}

.navbar {

    position: absolute;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 24px;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-89deg, #000000 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-89deg, #000000 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-89deg, #000000 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-179deg, #000000 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing {

    0% {
        background-position-y:511px
        }
    100% {
        background-position-y:0
        }
}

@-moz-keyframes swing {

    0% {
        background-position-y:511px
        }
    100% {
        background-position-y:0
        }
}

@-o-keyframes swing {

    0% {
        background-position-y:511px
        }
    100% {
        background-position-y:0
        }
}

@keyframes swing {

    0% {
        background-position-y:511px
        }
    100% {
        background-position-y:0
        }
}

.swing { 

    -webkit-transform-origin: center; 
    transform-origin: center; 
    -webkit-animation-name: swing; 
    animation-name: swing; 
}
```

**The problem is that the animation does not work in Firefox, but Chrome and other browsers work**

**Please see the video below, it speaks**

**http://sendvid.com/b1r3hofg**

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Have you tried adding `-moz-animation-name: swing;`?

Comment: Hi Bro. my version mozilla : 37.0.2

I to class swing
I added -moz-animation-name: swing;
But it is useless

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
  .swing {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center; 
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center; 
 -webkit-animation-name: swing; 
 -moz-animation-name: swing;
 animation-name: swing; 
  }
```

If this doesn't work, while it could be another code issue and you probably already know this, I'll just mention some CSS properties (transitions especially) are browser-dependent (meaning they only work for certain browsers)...although what you are doing seems like it should work.

Whatever the case, I wish you good luck friend! :)

Comment: Hi. Please update the image url. It is not accessible to us. :) ~Line 12 of your CSS: 
    background: #000000 url(../images/icons.svg) repeat center;

Comment: Hi dear, I don't mean that. My comment is: Can  you please provide the url for the image? I cannot see the image but want to replicate your situation. :)

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it :

@keyframes swing {

```
        0% {
    background-position: 0 511px;
    }
100% {
    background-position:0
    }
```

}